# Zip files in multiple directories to one zip then download to computer at certain time

Tags: java, php, download, automation, php-ziparchive

The title is quite a mouthful but here is what I am trying to accomplish.

**Step one:**

The script has to scan all the directories in the users folder the path would look like this;

```
"Users/$username/incomplete/"
```

From here it will collect all of the files in each path and temporarily move them to a new location I.E.;

```
"archives/"
```

This will have to be set to be done at a specific time lets say 10:00 P.M. so that it is all automated.

**Step two:**

Next it needs to turn all of these files into an zip file and unlink the files that were zipped (if they need to be deleted). The archive name needs to consist of the word incomplete followed by the date it was zipped. I.E.

```
"archives/incomplete-10-05-2013.zip"
```

These first two steps are probably relatively easy and I will be searching for ways of accomplishing this.

**Step three:**

Now once the file has been zipped I need it to download to a specific computer at lets say 12:00 A.M. Once again this has to be automated to reduce the complexity of the user interface.

This is the part that I i have no idea on how to do.

---

If you would like further details I am going to start putting together what I can from it and will try posing some coding on here.

Comment: Um The other computer would download it from it's location. The usual way of managing something like that. I to make it available from said time and then have the target machine download it some convenient time after that, unless you are in control of both machines. Even then this is a far more robust way of doing it.

Comment: i have decided to not have the last part automated instead the user will just download it and after it has been downloaded delete it